# Unable to use profile HTML snippet even when "use profile in external site" option is enabled

Tags: profile, settings

I've read around this but not found an obvious answer. I have "Accept profile submissions from external sites" set to "yes" under the "misc" options, and I'm at a bit of a loss - it would be really helpful to be able to embed profiles in pages.
Thanks. Were on Civi 5.58.1

Comment: Is the profile Used For: Standalone Form or Directory and active?
Be warned though, profiles used through snippets don't support recaptcha and that can result in a lot of spam submissions (fake contacts in your database). There are better options. Are you using an external site or the same site? Which CMS?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yep those options are selected - it seems strange its not there! We're using Drupal. Do you have any other suggestions for how we can embed a profile form?

Comment: Drupal webform is a good solution if it's the same site.
Not clear what you mean by unable to use the profile, like submissions don't show up?

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work really well! Cheers.